# Stateful and Functional stateless components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, stateless

How to convert Stateless functional components to stateful component in order to use lifecycle methods and passing props to it like Stateless Component.

```
( export default JobCard = (props) => { 
   ............
 }
)
```

I need to convert this to stateful component in order to use life-cycle method and pass props to the return function like how props is passed here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
export default class JobCard extends React.Component {
  render() {

    // here you can access props passing down from
    // parent components like: this.props

    return (
      <div>
        Hi, I'm a super smart component!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
Like let props = this.props ?

Comment: @PremKumar see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html for more information how props work within react-native

Comment: Yes, you can do that. In stateless components, you access props like `props.name`, in stateful components, you do it like `this.props.name`

Comment: @konekoya  Thank you